# Getting blank screen at start of xcode application, so how to call it programmatically?

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode

I have wasted 12 hours on something that should be so simple, yet every time I load my app in xcode, it gives me a black screen (and no, it's not the load screen). How do I call my storyboard window programmatically at launch so that I can move onto something more worthwhile in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but there should be an entry in your app-info.plist file called "main storyboard file base name" whose value should be the name of your start-up storyboard.

Comment: Yeah, but what code or links to dev pages can I use to go about calling my MainStoryboard_iPhone (the default one)

Comment: @user1776234, Not sure what you mean by "links to dev pages". If your main storyboard has an entry in the info.plist file, then you don't need to do anything to call it, it happens automatically. If you have that entry, then something else is the problem. Have you checked to make sure one of the controllers in the storyboard is set as the initial controller?

Comment: @user1776234, There's a check box in the Attributes Inspector -- select the controller you want to be the initial one, and check that box (called "Is Initial View Controller").

Comment: Yup. It's checked. Thanks for the advice though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1776234, not without more information. How did you make this app? Did you start it from one of the templates? Did you add the storyboard later? You need to provide a little more context.

Comment: I chose a single view template and started with a storyboard. I added some lines of code to the next viewcontroller like login to a remote mysql databse and then generate output onto a custom table view. However, that is not on the main screen, which simply has two buttons on it that trigger a simple segue transition. So how do I get this main screen loaded on startup (it is the one with the checkmark for initial view controller)

Comment: As I said, it should load automatically -- you could try it in code with: UIViewController *controller = [UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController]; Then self.window.rootViewController = controller. And finally (if it's not there already), [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Hmmm...it's telling me "no known class method" for instantiateInitialViewController...should I declare this as the class in the header or my actual view controller?

Comment: @user1776234, sorry about that -- I forgot you need to get the storyboard instance not the class. So, UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your name here" bundle:nil]. Then, [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]. I still don't think this will work, judging by how you started the project, the storyboard should be doing this automatically.

Comment: Ok. So, that partially worked. I say partially because now xcode is giving me an error instead of nothing (which must be the source of the problem). It is telling me my view controller is not in the view hierarchy. What should I do for that? (I have it linked up with a segue and this code in the view controller to get to another view controller: if (![[API sharedInstance] isAuthorized]) {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];